# java stream map class with relationship

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to to sum values of my class with join with another class with stream and map.

```
campaigns.stream().mapToLong(SmoochActiveCampaign::getSmoochActiveCampaignReport::getQtyPhoneConfirmed).sum();
```

my old code is this way...

```
    Long qtyMsgsApi = Long.valueOf("0");
    
    if (campaigns.size() > 0) {
        for (int indexTag = 0; indexTag < campaigns.size(); indexTag++) {
            

                qtyMsgsApi = qtyMsgsApi + campaigns.get(indexTag).getSmoochActiveCampaignReport().getQtyPhoneConfirmed();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What is your error? How does your List content look like?

Comment: You cannot use a method reference on another reference

Comment: Side note: there is no point in writing `Long qtyMsgsApi = Long.valueOf("0");` You can use `Long qtyMsgsApi = 0L;` utilizing auto-boxing, but there is no reason to use `Long` objects at all when summing. So just use `long qtyMsgsApi = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so.

- stream the list
- map to a long
- sum them.

```
long qtyMsgsApi = campaigns.stream()
        .mapToLong(campaign -> campaign.getSmoochActiveCampaignReport()
                .getQtyPhoneConfirmed())
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 campaigns.stream().mapToLong(campaign-> {
                return campaign.getSmoochActiveCampaignReport().getQtyPhoneConfirmed();
            }).sum();
```